Italian 90s movie about high school teacher
I saw this in the early 2000s, the movie is in Italian and looked 90s. A new (could be substitute but probably just fresh) teacher gets assigned to a poor Italian high school. 
The students give him a rough time, he then gives one of them a bad grade. In recess he locks the student/grade register in a cabinet of his desk. But during that recess, the kids pick the lock and change / modify the grades for that guy. When he comes back he discovers this, one of the kids tells him who did it. After the next recess he discovers "X is infame" written on the blackboard. X is the snitch student. At some point during this the students take the cabinet key from him, a girl puts it in her pants and he just grabs it from there. The teacher then goes on to explain the etymology of that word and the fact that colloquially it means snitch. He then asks them to explain the etymology of the word and only a guy answers, probably the snitch.
Another scene I remember is him going to the gas station where one of his students works and there the guy is friendly since now the teacher is a customer. The student explains briefly that he needs to survive and the school isn't really helping him, he doesn't need to know about the march on Rome or other such things.
There is also a scene where he gets into a fight with some local gang dealer  in a bar over the fact that another of hist students is a member of that guy's gang. The name Luca also comes to mind, it was either the teacher's name or some other character's

The general plot looks like that of "Mery per sempre" but the details don't quite match...

No, it wasn't a correction school, the guy was a simple young teacher that got assigned to a ghetto. Thank you, "Mery per sempre" is not even in the wikipedia list of "italian high school movies", it mostly has ones about hot women who happen to be teaching in high schools...
